# Subdividing a 3D surface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, surface

I am using MATLAB to create some diagrams to explain my research and am stuck on the following problem. I have created a half-ellipsoid rotated about the x-axis but I would like to demonstrate some internal structure within the ellipsoid which will be rotated around the x- and y-axes. This is roughly shown in the figure below, where I have subdivided the ellipsoid into four parts (with my bad paint skill).

[image]

How can I subdivide my ellipsoids into sections using planes of varying rotation about the x- and y-axes? I can create the ellipsoid and intersecting plane surfaces, but from there I don't know how to divide the ellipsoid up and change the face colours.

I have included some basic code below to get things started. I had thought I could just mask parts of the ellipsoid coordinates like I did to cut the ellipsoid in half, but this does not work. I am guessing I need to make some kind of mesh grid,but I don't know how to combine the grid from the intersecting surface and the ellipsoid.

```
figure
x   = 0;    y   = 0;    z   = 0;
tl  = 10;   tw  = 4;   td  = 2;

% Create ellipsoid
[ex,ey,ez]  = ellipsoid(x, y, z, tl, tw, td,40);
ex          = ex(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);   % Remove top half 
ey          = ey(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);   % of ellipsoid
ez          = ez(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);

% Make some planes
[ySL,zSL] = meshgrid([-10:10],[-2:0.2:2]);
xSL1 = zeros(size(ySL, 1)); % Generate z data
hSL1 = surf(xSL1,ySL,zSL);

hold on
[ySL,zSL] = meshgrid([-10:10],[-3:0.2:1]);
xSL2 = ones(size(ySL, 1)); % Generate z data
hSL2 = surf(xSL2,ySL,zSL);

% rotate(hSL,[1 0 0],5);
rotate([hSL1 hSL2],[0 1 0],-70);

hSurf1  = surf(ex,ey,ez);
set([hSurf1 hSL1 hSL2],'facecolor','blue','facealpha',.2,...
    'edgecolor','none')

% Plot settings
daspect([1 1 0.3]);
hold off
view(-10,6)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: In your code, `exR`, `eyR`, and `ezR` are undefined.

Comment: Good spotting - in my code I rotate the ellipsoid (hence the 'R') but this is not especially relevant to my problem. Have made the change.

Comment: Okay. So it's fine to replace `exR` by just `ex`, et cetera? Edit: Okay, seems like it is.

Comment: Yes - I have edited the code in the original question. I am happy with my ability to rotate the shapes/surfaces.

Comment: Another question: what format is the data you eventually want to plot in the ellipse? Just `(x,y,z)` points or a mesh of some sort?

Comment: This is primarily for a diagram and so the data format isn't so important for me. Ideally the objects would be nice and smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting question. So, here is a solution for 1) plotting three dimensional points inside the ellipse, bounded by the two planes, and 2) taking those points to form a smooth looking patch representation.

My basic idea is to build a mesh that covers (as densely as required) the whole X-Y-Z space of interest. What I then do is define the two [planes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) in the parametric form `ax+by+cz+d=0`. These are the planes between which the data is to be plotted. Using the normal vector of the planes, with information about a point on each of the planes, I can deduce using the dot product whether each point in the X-Y-Z grid is above or below the planes: if the dot product is less than zero, the point is above the plane, and if greater than zero, above the plane.

Using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) I then find which points on the grid satisfy the conditions 1) above plane 1, 2) below plane 2, and 3) inside the ellipsoid and -- optionally -- 4) below `Z=0`.

Finally, I plot the ellipsoid and the planes, along with the points that fulfil the criteria above.

In this case, I define two planes, but I guess you could do this for any number of them. The code is quick and dirty, but hopefully will give you a way forward!

```
% Define the ellipse
x   = 0;    y   = 0;    z   = 0;
tl  = 10;   tw  = 4;   td  = 2;

% Create ellipsoid
[ex,ey,ez]  = ellipsoid(x, y, z, tl, tw, td,40);
ex          = ex(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);   % Remove top half 
ey          = ey(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);   % of ellipsoid
ez          = ez(1:ceil(length(ez)/2),:);


% Define a 3D grid over area of interest
xx = linspace(min(ex(:)),max(ex(:)),50);
yy = linspace(min(ey(:)),max(ey(:)),50);
zz = linspace(min(ez(:)),max(ez(:)),50);
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(xx, yy, zz);
V = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)]; % rearrange

% Define two planes (ax + bx + cz + d = 0)
a = [0; 0];
b = [-1; 1];
c = [-1; 1];
d = [-1; -1];
% Normal vectors of the planes
n = [a b c];
n(1,:) = n(1,:) / norm(n(1,:));
n(2,:) = n(2,:) / norm(n(2,:));

% Find a point (0,0,z) on each plane
zp = [zeros(2) (d- a * 0 - b * 0)./c];

% Define the area of interest.
% Dot product to test if grid points are below or above the planes
% We want: above plane 1, below plane 2.
V1 = sum(bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@minus, V, -zp(1,:)), n(1,:)),2);
V2 = sum(bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@minus, V, -zp(2,:)), n(2,:)),2);
between_planes = (V1 < 0) & (V2 < 0);
% ...and the points have to be inside the ellipsoid
in_ellipse = ((X(:) - x)/tl).^2 + ((Y(:)-y)/tw).^2 + ((Z(:)-z)/td).^2 < 1;
% Final AOI
aoi = between_planes & in_ellipse;

% Add this if you want to also have only values with Z < 0
aoi = aoi & (V(:,3) < 0);

figure;
surf(ex, ey, ez, 'facecolor','blue','facealpha',.2,...
    'edgecolor','none')
```

So, now we are ready to plot some data! First up, let's try just plotting the grid to get a kind of discrete visualization with individual data points showing up:

```
hold on;
plot3(V(aoi,1), V(aoi, 2), V(aoi, 3), 'r.')
```

...just to see it works, let's add the planes we defined earlier to the visualization. This is something you probably want to get rid of eventually.

```
% Draw the planes
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);
Z = cell(2,1);
clr = {'r', 'g'};
for k = 1:2
    Z{k} = (a(k) * X + b(k) * Y + d(k))/ (-c(k));
    hs(k) = surf(xx, yy, Z{k},'facecolor',clr{k}, 'facealpha',.2, 'edgecolor','none');
    drawnow;
end
view([-115 10])
legend(hs, 'Plane 1 (above)', 'Plane 2 (below');
```

Well, finally, if we want to show some smooth looking data, we can use [`alphaShape`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html) to extract a polyhedra from those data points we have. We can visualize the polyhedra as a [`patch`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html) object just by using `plot`. Finally, we can assign any color we want to each of the vertices in the patch, set a smooth change to the visualized color by setting the `'Facecolor'` property, and remove the pesky vertex edges by setting `'EdgeColor'` to `'none'`:

```
% Moving on to smooth representation...
shp = alphaShape(V(aoi,1), V(aoi, 2), V(aoi, 3),1);
hs = plot(shp);
% Create a colormap to use for the patch (color of each vertex)
cmap = jet(size(hs.Vertices,1));
set(hs, 'FaceVertexCData', cmap);
set(hs, 'FaceColor', 'interp'); % smooth interp coloring
set(hs, 'EdgeColor', 'none'); % Remove ugly edges
```

So that's it. All that is left is to replace the vertex color values with whatever is appropriate for your data. Also, remember to skip the `plot3` part earlier if you don't want those data points to show up in the display along the patch.

Sample end result below, showing the two planes as well.
[image: End result.]

Comment: This is a good answer, but ideally instead of a grid I would have some kind of smooth surface (like the ellipsoid in my original post). Is this possible? I think the answer as it stands will help me on a related issue that I have, and I will upvote it when I have enough reputation...

Comment: @driftingtides Thanks! Turns out it's pretty straightforward to use those points to extract a polyhedra, for which we can set a nice smooth face color. I updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent. This answers my question. Because of the use of a regular grid/mesh the final polyhedron rendered does not match the original ellipsoid exactly. By making the grid finer I can mitigate this somewhat. Ultimately I would like to use some kind of parametric surface (e.g. [this question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102981/points-of-intersection-on-a-randomly-situated-plane-and-ellipsoid-spherical-in) but I might need to improve my geometry skills a tad.